# Replace All or Replace is not working in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 when i want to replace any thing in the entire project it not working. I need to go to each and every particular page and replacing. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Whats on the right side? Why dont you use preview? Are

Comment: thanks for your reply but its not working   -kuldeep & sulthan

Comment: @dahiya_boy NO i haven't can you help me with refactoring

Comment: I have the same problem. I've followed the instructions in the Help page exactly. At the last step it says to click the Replace All button, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Sulthan Preview is for doing replaces selectively. In fact, this highlights another problem I have: When I open the Preview, the replacement version column is all blank.